# C# Falling down label (moving up and down)

Tags: c#, timer, label

i want to do the following: with the timer the label2 is falling down, but i want when i press space the label to go up and when i release it the label to go down again until i press the space again, i wrote it like this, but it's keep falling down:

```
int step = 5;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Space:
                step = -5;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Location = new Point(label2.Location.X, label2.Location.Y + step);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Space:
                step = 5;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I created a new WinForms project with your code, and it's working for me.  Can you create a brand new project and see if the code still fails?  There may be something else in your application that is causing the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: really? how is that possible?

Comment: yes, is still doing the same, any other ideas?

Comment: Can you verify that all your events are wired up correctly?  Put a break point on the line `step = -5` in the `KeyDown` handler and see if your program breaks when you press the space bar.

Comment: is't it hitting the code when you set the break point?

Comment: Make sure you have KeyPreview() for the Form set to true.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: OP must have set it to `true' otherwise KeyUp event wouldnt have fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your events are not wired up.  Click on the form in the designer, then look at the `Properties` window.  Then click on the lightning bolt, which takes you to the Events pane.

[image]

If there's nothing next to `KeyDown`, the `Form1_KeyDown` method will not be called when you press a key.  Click the white space and select the method that will be called when the `KeyDown` event is fired.

If there are other controls on the form, you may need to have `KeyPreview` enabled as well.  This tells the form to respond to key presses when another control has focus.

[image]

Comment: is like in the picture...oh

Comment: Thank you too i put them again like in the picture, thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wireup the KeyDown Event properly

Try This:

```
this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
```

Comment: maybe because i have another timer with the code: this.Invalidate(); ?

Comment: ohh is it , then check it please , could you please share the code?